# How to store previous page name if user click navigates back in local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages and when I am on second page and go back to first page how would store previous page name.

first page:  `"some url"/first-page`

second page: `"some url"/first-page/second-page`

I am on second page and want to store first page name in local storage if I go back.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
         var referrer  = document.referrer;
  });
```

Local storage should have value as `"some url"/first-page` when I navigates to back page.

Comment: just use window.history.back like this <button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>

Comment: I want to navigate back using browser back button.It didn't seem to work

Comment: you can try this one <a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Go Back</a>

Comment: or `<a href="javascript: window.history.back()">Go Back</a>`

Comment: @prachijain Please provide  sample code or fiddle link regarding your issue